# Using alembic with multiple databases

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a pretty standard flask app. It uses `flask_sqlalchemy` to manage connections to a `postgres` server and `alembic` to manage migrations.

Now the issue is that I'm in the process of integrating it with another project and that means that I'm trying to allow it to pull a single model from another database. Luckily, `flask_sqlalchemy` has great support for this with the `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` flag. So I have my app with a new model set up like so:

```
class CoreUser(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'core'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
```

So far so good. My app now checks this other database when it should. Here's the minus though. Since I'm using `alembic` to actually manage all of the schemas in the database, when I run my typical `alembic revision --autogenerate` script, it doesn't actually do anything to this second database at all, and seems to just ignore the `__bind_key__` piece of the puzzle.

Instead, it sets up the proper `core_user` relation in the first database. How can I indicate to alembic that when it encounters this schema definition it should be creating the relation in a different database?

I've tried updating my `alembic.ini` file as shown below on the advice of [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/cCTXejFWX9o) (ancient) thread:

```
[core_db]
sqlalchemy.url = <DATABASE_URI>
script_location = alembic
```

And then running the following commands:

```
alembic -n core_db revision --autogenerate
alembic -n core_db upgrade head
```

And while the revision is generated and this doesn't fail, there are no relations actually created in the database indicated by the `core_db` `sqlalchemy.url` parameter.

I haven't been able to find any better documentation than that 4 year old Google group thread, but my current approach doesn't seem to be working and I don't have any obvious next steps. I'm unable to find the appropriate `alembic` documentation, but this seems like a very simple and common use case, so I can't imagine that this isn't supported.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you moved on with this issue finally? :)

Comment: @NikolayFominyh Yea, I ended up realizing that alembic doesn't actually handle this.

Comment: @SlaterVictoroff what did you use instead?

Comment: @fields manually hacked it with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to handle migrations for **many databases** with **different models**.

In our case, we have N databases with different models. Following structure helps to keep databases isolated:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── employee
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── migrations
│   └── user
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       └── views.py
├── daemon
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── daemon_engine.py
│   ├── migrations
│   └── models.py
├── run.py
└── tests
```

Comment: how do you run migrations fort particular databases ? Eg - if you wanted to run `alembic upgrade head` for the `app` database, where / how do you run that ?

Answer (score 2):

The steps you've taken so far are correct.

But, did you assign the correct `target_metadata` in `env.py` for each database?

If the metadata that is passed in is the same for both your databases, no different relations will be found and therefore the autogenerated script will not reflect what you're looking for.

Check which tables are associated with the metadata by looking at the `Base.metadata.tables` variable.

Pass in only the tables you want for each database `env.py`. You should have one for each database in their respective `script_location`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with `flask-sqlalchemy` and `alembic` by using `flask-migrate` and its `--multidb` option here:

https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiple-database-support

I then had to modify all of my old database migrations (when i only had one db) as mentioned here:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/181

Still running into a bit of trouble with the upgrade script in that it adds and removes all of my old tables to this new database. Not sure what that's about but will know soon...

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult. When creating a new revision with auto-generate feature, Alembic (as of `v1.11.3`) checks the history by connecting **ONLY** to one single database for the version table, and extract all the heads by accessing all script files in the folder `migrations/versions` (assume only one version path).

In other words Alembic always assumes there is only one database for  each migration folder. You will get error when upgrading the second (or subsequent) migrations to one of the databases

For those interested with implementation detail, check out the following functions :

- `MigrationContext.get_current_heads()` at [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/blob/main/alembic/runtime/migration.py), where Alembic verifies last commit history from database.
- `RevisionContext._run_environment()` at [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/blob/main/alembic/autogenerate/api.py), where Alembic loads the scripts of all the heads / branches, and compare with the result of the operation above.